# release cli in gitlab cannot do post request. How to write the command properly?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, release, jobs, gitlab-ci.yml

I want to set the artifact from previous job as the asset in the release, but it is said that the release-cli had failed to make a request to the gitlab url. How can I solve this?
Why I got this error?
Here is the error I am getting:

```
release-cli --insecure-https create --name="$VERSION" --description "$CI_COMMIT_TAG_MESSAGE" --tag-name="$VERSION" --assets-link='{"name":"docker_image.zip","url":"'$GE_JOB_URL'/artifacts/download?file_type=archive"}'
time="2023-09-01T13:14:03Z" level=info msg="Creating Release..." cli=release-cli command=create name= project-id=48 ref=7...02 server-url="http://<gitlab_url>" tag-message= tag-name= version=0.15.0
time="2023-09-01T13:14:34Z" level=fatal msg="run app" cli=release-cli error="failed to create release: failed to do request: Post \"http://<gitlab_url>/api/v4/projects/48/releases\": dial tcp <some IP with port>: i/o timeout" version=0.15.0
```

Here is the code in the gitlab yml file:

```
release: 
  stage: release
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest 
  needs:
    - job: build:image
      artifacts: true
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG 
    - when: always
  script:
    - echo "running release_job"
    - echo 'Previous Job ID is printed below'
    - echo $GE_JOB_ID
    - echo $GE_JOB_URL
    - release-cli --insecure-https create --name="$VERSION" --description "$CI_COMMIT_TAG_MESSAGE" --tag-name="$VERSION" --assets-link='{"name":"docker_image.zip","url":"'$GE_JOB_URL'/artifacts/download?file_type=archive"}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a `--server-url` flag.
(see [docs](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli/-/blob/master/docs/index.md#usage))

Yours is currently set to `server-url="http://gitlab_url"`, which is stated in your provided error message, and is obviously incorrect.

Comment: gitlab_url is the placeholder I put there, the url is private. I will try --server-url flag

Comment: Ah, I see. Strange... I just saw that it should take $CI_SERVER_URL as default.

Comment: is it possible that gitlab is set wrong? or something is missing?

Comment: I'm not quite sure about the `$GE_JOB_URL` does thas env var really get substituted? (in the assets-link)

Comment: in the echo i can see the job url

Comment: I think it should be: `release-cli --insecure-https create --name="$VERSION" --description "$CI_COMMIT_TAG_MESSAGE" --tag-name="$VERSION" --assets-link='{"name":"docker_image.zip","url":"$GE_JOB_URL/artifacts/download?file_type=archive"}' ` (without the single quotes)